# Antivirus block website due to JS:MagentoStealer-A [Trojan]

Tags: antivirus

Avast Antivirus showing that our website is infected with JS:MagentoStealer-A [Trojan] and block to connect it.

The website works for those who don't use Avast.

What should I do?

Magento 1.9.4.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think your site has been compromised with Malware or other Malicious Code:

- Scan your site with a tool like magereport.com
- Apply all patches
- Check for any unknown files in the system
- Review and remove all unknown admin accounts
- Change all remaining admin passwords to strong ones (e.g., they
  should be long, and include symbols, upper and lower case letters,
  and numbers)
- Follow best practices outlined in the Magento User Guide